# Key use case differences of using AWS security group and Network ACL

Tags: security, networking, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I know the stateful/stateless nature of Network ACL and Security Group; and I also know Network ACL is associated to subnet(s) whereas Security Group is associated to instance(s).

The above two are most noticeable difference where we should encode our security policy in.

However, are there any use cases that we can clearly see one is better than the other?

For example, right now, I am thinking of lock-down the bastion host's network security. I can encode it into a security group sg_A {only allow 22 from a set of know IP ranges for the ingress traffic} and associate sg_A to the bastion instance. I can also encode it into a network ACL net_acl_B {only allow 22 from a set of know IP ranges for the ingress traffic} and associate net_acl_B to the subnet that the bastion instance is located.

Answer (score 3):

> I can also encode it into a network ACL net_acl_B {only allow 22 from a set of know IP ranges for the ingress traffic} and associate net_acl_B to the subnet that the bastion instance is located.

Not quite.

The default network ACL *already* allows all traffic in and out.  Explicitly allowing specific traffic there doesn't change anything, since everything is allowed out of the box.

Security groups, conversely, allow nothing inbound by default.

You'd still have to also allow bastion host access in the security group, because **both entities have to allow all traffic you want to pass.**  Neither one overrides the rules of the other for "allow" -- they have to agree.

Network ACLs, being stateless, also have to allow the response traffic, while security groups, being Stateful, don't.

Rule 1: Use security groups for access control.  There is essentially never a reason to open a security group wide open and then turn around and use and network ACL as the sole firewall layer.

Rule 2 Option A: Only use network ACLs to only implement restrictions that are not possible with security groups, such as blocking traffic from a small subnet carved out of a larger subnet that is allowed.

Rule 2 Option B: Use network ACLs to duplicate the logic of the rules in the security groups, as a physically-first, logically-second layer of defense against unintentionally-permissive security group misconfiguration.